# Tell mplayer to prevent the screensaver from kicking in while playing

Tags: mplayer, screensaver

I know mplayer has some heartbeat setting but I don't recall what it is, could anyone tell me?

*another one of those annoying things that used to just work and somewhere along the line stopped being default*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mplayer` has the switch `-heartbeat-cmd` to run a command every 30 seconds, but as the man page says:

> This can be "misused" to disable screensavers that do not support the proper X API

The actual switch meant to disable screensavers is `-stop-xscreensaver`; you should probably try that first

Comment: I put `-stop-xscreensaver` in `~/.mplayer/config` when trying to play a video I got this error: `Option -stop-xscreensaver needs a parameter at line 2` ideas?

Comment: @xeno Every option in the config file needs to have a value; if it's just a boolean flag, set it equal to `true`, `yes`, or `1`. You also shouldn't include the `-` when you're using the config file, so you'll get a warning about an unknown option (it sees your entry for `-stop-xscreensaver` and looks for the flag `--stop-xscreensaver`); it should read `stop-xscreensaver=true` instead

Comment: now if only I could do the same thing with flash/<video>

Comment: @xenoterracide you can use mplayer to watch flash videos, load the video, look in /tmp and play the video with mplayer :P

Answer (score 2):

`mplayer -stop-xscreensaver` does not work for me (Debian wheezy; xscreensaver=5.15-3, xfce4=4.8.0.3, mplayer=2:1.0~rc4.dfsg1+svn34540-1+b2) - the screensaver still comes on during the movie. I wrote a screensaver inhibition tool `xscreensaver-inhibit`, and an mplayer wrapper `play`. `xscreensaver-inhibit` is useful for other things like youtube so I put a shortcut on my panel for it.

`$HOME/bin/xscreensaver-inhibit` is as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
usage () {
    echo "usage: $0 [on|off]"
    echo '    Turns screensaver inhibition on or off.'
    echo '    default: toggle on/off'
    exit 1;
}

if [ -n "$1" ]  ; then
    [ "$1" = "on" -o "$1" = "off" ] || usage
fi

inhibit () {
    while [ -f "$lock" ] ; do
        # echo "$lock exists"
# UPDATE Dec 2018 this command seems to have stopped working after upgrading to Debian Stretch.
        # DISPLAY=:0 xdg-screensaver reset
# Replaced with this command which is working for me,
# though if you do not use xscreensaver you might need something else.
        DISPLAY=:0 xscreensaver-command -deactivate
        sleep 50
    done
    # echo "$lock is gone"
}

lock="/tmp/xsi.lock"

if [ -e "$lock" ] ; then
    echo 'Screensaver currently inhibited.'
    on='on'
else 
    echo 'Screensaver operating normally.'
    on=''
fi

if [ "$1" = "on" ] ; then
    if [ -n "$on" ] ; then
        echo 'Starting screensaver inhibitor anyway.'
    else 
        echo 'Screensaver inhibitor started.'
    fi
    touch "$lock" && inhibit &
fi

if [ "$1" = "off" ] ; then
    if [ -n "$on" ] ; then
        echo 'Screensaver inhibitor(s) stopped.'
    else 
        echo 'Perhaps the screensaver daemon is not running or another program is inhibiting it.'
    fi
    rm -f "$lock"
fi

if [ ! -n "$1" ] ; then
    if [ -n "$on" ] ; then
        echo 'Screensaver inhibitor(s) stopped.'
        rm -f "$lock"
    else 
        echo 'Screensaver inhibitor started.'
        touch "$lock" && inhibit &
    fi
fi
```

`$HOME/bin/play` is as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

xscreensaver-inhibit on

DISPLAY=:0 mplayer -fs "$@"

xscreensaver-inhibit off
```

I included `DISPLAY=:0` so the movie will play on the local active display even when I am logged in over SSH. `play` is also the default handler for all movie files in my file manager.

Note that `sox` provides `/usr/bin/play` so if you have `sox` installed, you might want to call `play` something else.

You can write similar wrappers for your other fullscreen apps that you don't want the screensaver interrupting.

`xscreensaver-inhibit` works on all DEs, Linuxes, and screensavers on which I have tried it. In case you get `xdg-screensaver: command not found`, run `apt-get install xdg-utils`.

UPDATE Dec 2018 changed main command in `xscreensaver-inhibit` from `xdg-screensaver` to `xscreensaver-command` - NOT tested on all DEs, Linuxes, screensavers. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

For me it's `--stop-screensaver`

When using --stop-xscreensaver the mplayer warns me: *option --stop-xscreensaver was replaced with --stop-screensaver and might be removed in the future.*

Debian & mpv 0.23.0 (C) 2000-2016 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects

Comment: Are you quoting from somewhere?   If so, please identify the source.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.